# How can I create a .env file in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dotenv

I have an app deployed on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance.  I use dotenv for development, but manually input my environment variables in production to avoid exposing them on GitHub.

My goal is to create a .env file outside my app directory so that I don't have to manually input my environment variables each time I deploy new code.

I've configured dotenv as follows:

`require("dotenv").config({ path: "../../environment-variables/Ticketing-App/.env" });`

Running "sudo touch .env" inside the Ticketing-App directory neither creates the file nor generates an error.

Is it possible to create a .env file on Ubuntu?  If so, how?

Comment: Can you specify the path variable with an absolute instead of `../../` ?

Comment: I think I could do that, but I'm still left with the issue of not being able to create the .env file.  There must be some alternative out there.

Answer (score 0):

Touch creates the file. You created a hidden file by adding the period in front of the file name. If you do `cat .env` you should get a print in the terminal. Doing `nano .env` will allow you to edit the file.

Comment: You don't need to `touch` the file first. You can give a nonexistent file to editors like `nano` and they'll create it when you save.